# Multiple ARIMA and VECM by group

Tags: r, arima

I want to perform multiple ARIMA and VECM at the same time.

Specifically, I want a time series for every "Sector", which goes from 2007Q1 to 2018Q4.

I tried to do it with a for loop but it is not working properly.

Is there a specific function to create this kind of result?

**Data**

```
structure(list(Sector = c("Administraci<U+00F3>n P<U+00FA>blica", 
"Administraci<U+00F3>n P<U+00FA>blica", "Administraci<U+00F3>n P<U+00FA>blica", 
"Administraci<U+00F3>n P<U+00FA>blica", "Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", 
"Agropecuaria", "Agropecuaria", "Alquiler de Viviendas", "Alquiler de Viviendas", 
"Alquiler de Viviendas", "Alquiler de Viviendas", "Comercio", 
"Comercio", "Comercio", "Comercio", "Comunicaciones", "Comunicaciones", 
"Comunicaciones", "Comunicaciones", "Construcci<U+00F3>n", "Construcci<U+00F3>n", 
"Construcci<U+00F3>n", "Construcci<U+00F3>n", "Electricidad, Gas y Agua", 
"Electricidad, Gas y Agua", "Electricidad, Gas y Agua", "Electricidad, Gas y Agua", 
"Explotaci<U+00F3>n de Minas y Canteras", "Explotaci<U+00F3>n de Minas y Canteras", 
"Explotaci<U+00F3>n de Minas y Canteras", "Explotaci<U+00F3>n de Minas y Canteras", 
"Hoteles, Bares y Restaurantes", "Hoteles, Bares y Restaurantes", 
"Hoteles, Bares y Restaurantes", "Hoteles, Bares y Restaurantes", 
"Intermediaci<U+00F3>n Financiera, Seguros y Otras", "Intermediaci<U+00F3>n Financiera, Seguros y Otras", 
"Intermediaci<U+00F3>n Financiera, Seguros y Otras", "Intermediaci<U+00F3>n Financiera, Seguros y Otras", 
"Manufactura", "Manufactura", "Manufactura", "Manufactura", "Otros Servicios", 
"Otros Servicios", "Otros Servicios", "Otros Servicios", "Servicios de Ense<U+00F1>anza", 
"Servicios de Ense<U+00F1>anza", "Servicios de Ense<U+00F1>anza", 
"Servicios de Ense<U+00F1>anza", "Servicios de Salud", "Servicios de Salud", 
"Servicios de Salud", "Servicios de Salud", "Transporte y Almacenamiento", 
"Transporte y Almacenamiento", "Transporte y Almacenamiento", 
"Transporte y Almacenamiento"), Fecha = c("2007 Q1", "2007 Q2", 
"2007 Q3", "2007 Q4", "2007 Q1", "2007 Q2", "2007 Q3", "2007 Q4", 
"2007 Q1", "2007 Q2", "2007 Q3", "2007 Q4", "2007 Q1", "2007 Q2", 
"2007 Q3", "2007 Q4", "2007 Q1", "2007 Q2", "2007 Q3", "2007 Q4", 
"2007 Q1", "2007 Q2", "2007 Q3", "2007 Q4", "2007 Q1", "2007 Q2", 
"2007 Q3", "2007 Q4", "2007 Q1", "2007 Q2", "2007 Q3", "2007 Q4", 
"2007 Q1", "2007 Q2", "2007 Q3", "2007 Q4", "2007 Q1", "2007 Q2", 
"2007 Q3", "2007 Q4", "2007 Q1", "2007 Q2", "2007 Q3", "2007 Q4", 
"2007 Q1", "2007 Q2", "2007 Q3", "2007 Q4", "2007 Q1", "2007 Q2", 
"2007 Q3", "2007 Q4", "2007 Q1", "2007 Q2", "2007 Q3", "2007 Q4", 
"2007 Q1", "2007 Q2", "2007 Q3", "2007 Q4"), PIB = c(10305185296.03, 
11271643560.5347, 12098530196.9999, 16713325912.2845, 24472582625.9992, 
25317947227.8876, 19847850207.0073, 25327489432.7455, 26655734015.1105, 
27434842375.117, 28384597142.3195, 29605364776.5822, 29003307533.2502, 
31486914082.706, 32956584613.8957, 38782177503.5912, 7270504656.88951, 
7418832680.51211, 8042405079.88414, 8335496341.28287, 34985837388.9214, 
37454607388.9239, 38355946491.0166, 40468340639.2155, 6745860903.25905, 
7008427188.3676, 7716448322.6911, 7577439666.14092, 7482109661.40208, 
8927736668.0929, 6753069442.04506, 5335570076.69075, 33170696094.6616, 
28130217096.5318, 27979455745.9348, 27635295391.0852, 14103359181.4247, 
13593532712.1383, 14488043582.0877, 15700283110.7247, 55075166803.6152, 
57775991400.8368, 59842233144.2308, 63996933498.6379, 28508327005.1848, 
28910333966.9294, 29465238026.753, 29983486174.9247, 10757709668.6044, 
10959059500.1544, 11626287995.6996, 12835248484.4039, 7896828222.42626, 
8491939213.95125, 8533061356.54159, 9075779808.57032, 23097019204.2543, 
24331042684.1632, 26951726625.0964, 29165061280.4721), Recaudacion = c(11040000, 
13850000, 20440000, 18020000, 33150000, 40850000, 50970000, 43180000, 
184990000, 245390000, 218460000, 206090000, 2066170000, 1857580000, 
1.911e+09, 1894070000, 1127110000, 852220000, 864970000, 1004680000, 
220140000, 257690000, 253800000, 233630000, 43560000, 50360000, 
46650000, 68380000, 9410000, 14150000, 15250000, 19370000, 1024400000, 
981650000, 709390000, 638460000, 1028600000, 766930000, 700950000, 
709530000, 2295170000, 2579500000, 2614010000, 2814790000, 533580000, 
617030000, 617140000, 661190000, 5200000, 6660000, 7230000, 6870000, 
7730000, 12920000, 15570000, 15380000, 446190000, 529540000, 
551330000, 567160000)), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the code below which transforms your dataset into a tidy format, creates a function for an arima model and then iterates all the existing series. 
You can add a VECM to that function or change the model inside the function.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)
library(forecast)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Sector,Fecha), names_to = 'Measure', values_to = 'Value') %>%
  mutate(Fecha = as.Date(as.yearqtr(Fecha))) %>%
  unite('Key', c(Sector,Measure), sep = '@') %>%
  arrange(Key) -> df #tidy format

unique_series <- unique(df$Key) #unique number of series 

Model <- function(i) {

  df %>% 
    filter(Key == unique_series[i]) -> Item #filter one single series

  #perform auto.arima
  model <- auto.arima(ts(Item$Value, start = Item$Fecha[1], frequency = 4))

}

lapply(1:length(unique_series), Model)
```